# Why might pymongo `find` produce inconsistent behavior?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have a MongoDB database with ~30 million documents. It's served from a single multiprocessor computer (144 GB RAM, running CentOS 7.1), and not sharded. I query it with pymongo 3.2.2, using Python 3.4.  The database is lightly used, with a small number of writers currently updating records.  Here is a situation where `find` does not return consistent results:

```
count = 0
for entry in mycollection.find({'fork': {'parent': None, 'root': None}}, {'_id': 1}):
    count += 1
print(count)
```

When run multiple times, sometimes this code prints 72, and sometimes it prints a much larger number (in excess of 2874400).  The larger number is not always the same, and from what I know of my data, the larger number is more likely to be correct.  Still, I'm at a loss to explain why it would sometimes print 72.

What are potential causes of this inconsistent behavior?

(Note: yes, I know I can use the `count(...)` operator to count the number of matching documents. The code above is fragment meant to illustrate the inconsistency, not to present an efficient way of counting the matching documents.)